# window.location.reload(); not working for Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using AJAX action after getting the response, I want to reload the current page, for which I am using:

```
 window.location.reload();
```

It works fine on Firefox and IE, but it's not working for Chrome; the content which I want display empty.

Is there way to reload the page in chrome?

```
window.opener.document.location.reload();
self.close();
```

Comment: I just tested and it work. Anything showing in the Chrome's JavaScript console?

Comment: Do you mean you (1) get an AJAX response (2) reload the page (3) then the content is gone?

Comment: yes for eg. am deleting the selected music file from drop down list through ajax in response am getting deleted successfully. To get the latest list am reloading the current page, at this movement the remaining filed content is also going and displaying empty.

Comment: Of course they are gone because you refreshed the page and your old content generated dynamically (or the user has input) will **not** be saved.

Comment: But same eg is working fine in firefox and IE

Comment: -1 and voting to close since you haven't given us a minimal example (supposedly there's an Ajax request involved in this, which presumably is in some way crucial, but you haven't shown us any code involving Ajax) and you haven't explained clearly what the actual problem is; you've stated *"the content which I want display empty"* but firstly because of the broken grammar I can't tell if you mean you want the content to be empty but it isn't, or vica versa, and secondly it's unclear what, if anything, this has to do with either the Ajax request or the page reload. This is unintelligible.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure why, but in my case i fixed it by wrapping the reload() call in a setTimeout with 100 ms.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
},100);
```

Answer (score 8):

try the below:

```
window.location = self.location;
```

above code does not work for some browsers, you can even try:

```
location.reload( true );
```

Comment: i used tried but not working same result,displays with empty fileds

Comment: window.location = self.location; works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
window.location.href = window.location;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:
   `parent.window.location.reload();`
  This doesn't work in Firefox 17 for me.

The only other way I know that works in all browsers is to redirect to another blank page and redirect back to the current page.

Answer (score -2):

Try this to reload page using JavaScript.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
window.self.close();
```

This works for me on all major browsers.

Answer (score -2):

If you are working with AJAX, you have to do the reload inside the success function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: '',
    url: '',
    success: function(data){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        },100);
    },
    error: function(){
}
```