# redirect after alert message not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a snippet of a js file>

```
$('#btnYes').on('click', (function() {
var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
var usertype = $('#myModal').data('usert');

$.ajax({

  url: '{site_url()}admin/deleteUserFromList',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {id: id, userT: usertype},
  success: function(html){

    $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    alert('usuario borrado');
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
 return false;

}));
```

as you can see there is an alert message after deleting a user from a list.

I want to refresh the page after ok on alert message is pressed so i added the line>

```
window.location.reload();
```

but it's not working, why is this? how can i fix it?

I've been trying to use alternative to this like

```
location.href = '....';

window.location = '/some/url';
```

but nothing seems to work!

this is in my admin.php, the code for deleting user from the database:

```
public function deleteUserFromList(){

    if ((isset($_POST['id']) && (isset($_POST['userT'])))){
        $rowId = $_POST['id'];
        $userType = $_POST['userT'];

        $result = array();

        if($userType == 'front'){
            $front = UserManager::getInstance()->getUser($rowId);
            UserManager::getInstance()->deleteItem($front);

        }else{
            $back = UserBackManager::getInstance()->getUser($rowId);
            UserBackManager::getInstance()->deleteItem($back);
        }
        $result["message"] = "Usuario eliminado";

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine in Chrome 31 on ubuntu... Is this perhaps a browser related issue?

Comment: In other words: what browser are you using?

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) `location.reload` method implemented in every browser.

Comment: @antindexer: that's the exact function he's using.

Comment: @Lix hi, im using Chrome 31 on windows 8. I have no errors after inspect it with chrome tool

Comment: @Cerbrus im using latest chrome version on win 8

Comment: The alert window is showing?

Comment: Check whether your ajax call successfully completed or not then.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, the alert is showing and deleting entire row is done. But i need to update a counter after deleting the row, that is why i need to refresh the page

Comment: @antindexer yes ajax call is working, the row is being deleted and the alert of that is showing.

Comment: have you tried window.location.href = "" ?  Although the others should work... just a suggestion

Comment: So, the alert _is_ showing, but `window.location.reload()` is not doing anything in chrome... Weird. Can you `console.log(window.location.reload)` for us?

Comment: As an aside, I think `.closest("tr")` is more appropriate than `.parents("tr")` (unless you have nested tables and want to remove the row in the outermost table).

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox yes, but it doesnt work either

Comment: Have you tried it in any alternative browsers?

Comment: dumb question, but why do you want to reload page in the first place? Seems to defeat purpose of using ajax to submit data

Comment: To update a counter on the page.  I was wondering if there would be another way to do that, but didn't want to ignore the main issue...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114725/window-location-reload-not-working-for-google-chrome  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967532/window-location-reload-not-working-for-firefox-and-and-chrome    have some suggestions

Comment: @charlietfl i need to update the counter (number of users in the list). It counts the objects (users), that why i need to refresh

Comment: can't you just return count from ajax? and do any DOM updates in success callback?

Comment: @charlietfl i have a function that automatically counts number of objects once the page is loaded. returning it via ajax wont be a cool fix, i guess

Comment: so count if after ajax too... otherwise to me you might just as well send form without ajax

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox i have just tryied with firefox but its not working either

Comment: As @charlietfl says, could you count the number of users in the ajax script and have it return the number as data to your current page?

Comment: Wait a second are you doing ajax on your modal window button click? and trying to redirect it?

Comment: @antindexer i guess so... is that wrong? im learning

Comment: Can you publish your code also here?

Comment: @antindexer right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simulate redirect in your browser try to:

**Javascript way:**

`window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

**jQuery way:**

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Try this and let me know it it works for you or not.

**EDIT:**
Inside ajax success. Try to close modal window and try to replace method.

**EDIT 2:**
Put this part of code inside of your document ready block and check is it fired or not if it is fired it means your form is reloading correctly.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  alert( "Bye now!" );
});
```

Comment: thx for this, but nothing seems to work and im driving nuts >s

Comment: Do you know how to debugging in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @charlietfl's comment, could you try something like this?

Return the count from the ajax script and insert it into your page:

```
$('#btnYes').on('click', (function() {
  var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
  var usertype = $('#myModal').data('usert');

  $.ajax({

    url: '{site_url()}admin/deleteUserFromList',   // this returns the user count as data
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id: id, userT: usertype},
    success: function(data){

      $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
      $('#countDisplayElement').text(data);  // insert new count into current page
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      alert('usuario borrado');
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
 return false;

}));
```

That would eliminate the need to refresh the page entirely and be a bit more friendly to use.