# `window.location.reload` doesn't reload page in Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, magento

I am using following code to let the user log into Magneto with AJAX. If the correct username and password is entered the page will refresh and display the user navbar in the header. The field works in Firefox, Safari and IE but not in Chrome. I have to refresh the page for the navbar to display.

Why does this problem occur?

Code:

```
AjaxLoginForm.submit = function(button){
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        // show ajax image
        // button.insert({"after":osc_ajax_loading_small});
        AjaxLoginForm.hideLoader();
        AjaxLoginForm.insertLoader(button);

        $("ajaxlogin_form").request({
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

                    if(json.is_forgot_pwd){
                        if(json.success){
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<div>"+json.success_message+"</div>");
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                        }
                        if(json.error){
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<div>"+json.error_message+"</div>");
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                        }
                    }else{                          
                        if(json.success){
                            // If the correct username and password is entered
                            // the page will refresh and display user navbar
                            // in the header
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                        if(json.error){
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").update("<div>"+json.error_message+"</div>");
                            $("ajaxlogin_form_message").show();
                        }
                    }
                    AjaxLoginForm.hideLoader();
                    //setTimeout("AjaxLoginForm.hideResponseMessage()", 5000);
                }
        });

    }
}.bind(AjaxLoginForm);
```

Comment: Try to add `true` as parameter to the `reload` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: @dlopez The problem is not resolved by add `true` to the `reload` method.

Comment: It seems that other people had the same problem, and there are some ways to handle it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114725/window-location-reload-not-working-for-google-chrome

Comment: just add a little timeout

Comment: in my case it works just fine in chrome `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Look at the Google Chrome Console, perhaps there a previous javascript error that is preventing to be executed the reload.

Comment: @dlopez that can be issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I am preety sure in chrome `window.location = self.location;` should work, or try `location.reload( true );` otherwise by callback some other function to reload your page.  
Otherwise you should get some error that prevents reload, you can get a console in success.

Comment: The problem is not resolved by `window.location = self.location;` :(

Answer (score 3):

You can try it with a `setTimeout`.Also you can simplify the code,currently you are writting `json.success` and `json.error` multiple times which should be written once.

```
setTimeout(function(){    
           window.location.reload();    
},100);
```

Comment: I used this method, but the problem persists!!

Comment: Now I suspect why are you writing json.success and failure two times?

Comment: The problem in these cases are not related. Because this code works properly in other browsers.

Comment: then OP needs to exactly tell us where is exactly problem?looks like there is other problem than `location.reload(); ` .Because location.reload() works in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For script is in iframe `top.location.reload()` works for me.