# Chrome: location.reload() of popup not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reload

In short, I have a project where I need to test XSS payloads for their validity. (if they still work or not) After some time I came to the conclusion, that the best way to test these payloads, is by creating a popup window, writing the payload, refreshing the popup and closing the popup. The code looks like the following:

```
function create_window_window_opt()
{
    if(payloads.length > 0)
    {
        var popup = window.open();
        popup.focus();
        var payload = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + payloads.shift() + "<script>setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},100);</scr"+"ipt></html>";
        popup.document.write(payload);
        setTimeout(function(){popup.close();create_window_window_opt();},200);
    }
}
```

The location.reload() is necessary for some payloads to trigger. Though, when reloading the popup in chrome, it seems that the content is completely gone. This problem has already been adressed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114725/window-location-reload-not-working-for-google-chrome) question, however the proposed solutions didn't work.
So here is my question:

Is there a solution to this problem, or do you have any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is communication between to browser windows or any form XSS, i suggest to check out postMessage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: No, communication between the windows is not the issue. The problem is, that location.reload() in the temporary window somehow deletes the content of the temporary window, and therefore doesn't really reload the window. Since some XSS payloads only trigger after a reload, these payloads would not get detected.