# DocuSign API Authentication redirect problem

Tags: docusignapi

We are having a problem with DocuSign redirect that is rather sudden and unexpected. I wonder if you can help.

After authenticating the code that is called via redirect does several things and at the end does these simple javascript commands:

```
<script>
    window.opener.location.reload(true);

    window.close();
</script>
```

Now this has worked great for years. But suddenly the first line (window.opener.location.reload(true)) is not working. That first line attempts to refresh the original screen before closing the redirect screen. But instead we are getting a console error saying :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')

I am suspicious that this is because of a server setting because coincidentally our server host made some changes yesterday.

Could this be due to some server settings? Is there some port that needs to be whitelisted for DocuSign or something like that? Ever seen this before?

I tried different methods of reloading the previous screen but to no avail.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Must be a race condition where the script is called prematurely. You can see a similar question here - [window.location.reload(); not working for Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114725/window-location-reload-not-working-for-google-chrome)

This has nothing to do with DocuSign. It's your code/page. You may want to put a timer before you run this code to avoid the race condition issue.